# Google Maps SDK for iOS? CoreLocationDelegate

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7

I am working on an iOS 7 app that needs ultimate accuracy in showing user location, I need to use google maps as well. This app will continually show walking directions for the user from one location to another.

I started with the corelocation framework and delegate, and configured my CLLocationManager like this

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[_locationManager setDelegate:self];
self.locationManager.headingOrientation = CLDeviceOrientationFaceUp;
[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness;
```

Now I went on to integrate the google maps SDK using cocoapods, and downloaded the googleSDK Samples, But I notice that in their own samples Google does not use a CLLocationManager, but rather it seems that the SDK picks up the location by itself.

My question is : Is this optimal? can I configure the accuracy of the geolocation service in the Google SDK? has anyone used that and had any issues?

I just don't wanna invest in Google SDK and throw away the native apple provided CLLocationManager.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, same like you would use Core Location and Apple's MKMapKit. Each framework is used for something else and if you do need mapping as well as some information only available in Core Location, you can subscribe to both.

If you do need google's mapping and it will provide you with location data you need, then you can skip Core Location.